# what is the mass of chromium in this sample?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

If the total number of atoms in a sample of potassium dichromate is $2.13\cdot10^{24}$ , then the amount of chromium in this sample is?
the answer that I've come up with is $367.64\ \mathrm g$
but in fact the solution in my book is $33.4\ \mathrm g$.

Comment: Well how did you come up with your answer?

Comment: 2.13*10^24/6.022*10^23=3.54 mol *2=7.07 since the molecular form of the compound is K2Cr2O7 , then I"v calculated the mass by multiplying moles by 52

Answer (score 1):

I like to solve such assignments using `Python` as a scientific calculator.

```
import scipy.constants 

# number of atoms in sample
N_ATOMS_TOTAL = 2.13E+24 

# atomic mass of chromium
M_CR = 51.9961 # g/mol

# ratio of chromium atoms to total atoms in K2Cr2O7
CR_RATIO = 2/11

# moles of Cr in sample
n_cr = N_ATOMS_TOTAL * CR_RATIO / scipy.constants.Avogadro

mass_cr = n_cr * M_CR # mass of chromium in g

mass_cr
```

Let me explain:

- You have an unknown mass (in gramm) of potassium dichromate, $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$.
- The total number of atoms in this sample is $2.13\cdot10^{24}$.

#### How can you calculate the number of chromium atoms in the sample?

- You need to determine the ratio of $\ce{Cr}$ to all atoms in $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$, and that's $\frac{2}{11}$ atoms.

#### I know the number of $\ce{Cr}$ atoms now, but how many moles is that?

- You know that 1 mol of an element has $6.02214129\cdot10^{23}$ atoms of that element (Avogadro's number).
- Divide the number of $\ce{Cr}$ atoms determined before by Avogadro's number to determine the number of moles of $\ce{Cr}$.

#### I know the number of moles of $\ce{Cr}$ now, but what is the weight?

- You know that the standard atomic weight of $\ce{Cr}$ is 51.9961.
- Multiply  the standard atomic weight with the number of moles to get the weight.

Comment: Im so confused :( , I know that when a substance like H20 has 2.5 mol it means H has number of moles=2*2.5 . but If I used the way u solved the question it will be 2 H atoms+1 O atom=3 atoms , to calculate H it will be (2/3)*2.5 and the result is different then :(

Comment: @119j7fly $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ has  2 $\ce{K}$ +  2 $\ce{Cr}$ + 7 $\ce{O}$ atoms, that's 11 atoms in total. Two of these are $\ce{Cr}$ atoms. This means that the number of $\ce{Cr}$ atoms in the sample is 2/11 * the total number of atoms :)

Comment: its very clear right now thanx a lot mr Klaus.